Where has the fat gone, why can I hardly see any fat here?
In the picture you can see the remainder of some fried chicken breast, carrot, Potatoe and tomatoes.  There is no chicken breast remaining in the picture.
When cooking I used two teaspoons of tallow, no other oil or fat.  At the end of cooking after everything cooled down and reached room temperature I expected the tallow to solidify and so I could see it in the same way you see oil when frying with oil.  However from the pic you can see there is no remaining visible tallow.
Usually when frying whether it’s deep, shallow or stir-fry, from
Most to less, in that order I think you’ll notice the oil at the end.  However I can hardly notice any fat here.

Can I hardly see any fat because I used too little(2 teaspoons for a chicken breast and some vegetables) and this was like a stir fry so there will be very little solid fat remaining in the pan?

Where did those 2 teaspoons of fat go?  If it were absorbed into the food shouldn’t I see it solidly on the surface of the food at room temperature?

If I want more fat sauce is it just the case that I needed to use a lot more fat to begin? How much more - the stuff I’m using is quite expensive.

The vegetables did cook and you could break it with your fingers but the texture wasn’t like deep fried chips or even boiled potatoes which are very soft. It was more like partially boiled potatoes.  Would you say besides the tomatoe, the Potatoe and carrots were too big and stir fried while perhaps a meal like this should be shallow or deep fried to be fully cooked?


Thanks


Maybe edit the question to focus on one problem, (3) looks like it could be a separate question.


The fat would have emulsified with the water released by the vegetables (a bit like how mayonnaise works), that's why you can't see any free fat in there. If you want to be able to see the fat you can either add more (at any stage of cooking), or cook out enough of the liquid that the emulsion breaks and the fat separates again. It would end up very mushy probably.
Yes, it's up to you how much more fat, I don't think there are any hard rules here.
I'm not entirely sure what you mean by this question so I'll try and give you some info that I think is relevant. In general harder vegetables take longer to cook than softer ones, and larger pieces take longer than smaller ones. You can add the things that take longer earlier in the process or cut them smaller so everything can be cooked together. Or you can use a microwave to partially cook the potato and carrot before it goes in the pan.


Regarding the third part of my question, as you said harder and bigger takes longer.  These were hard vegetables, sized like large fries.  Would I be right thinking 2 teaspoons of fat is a low amount for this?  As such would one typically use a lot more fat to fry something like this?  Thanks.

You said fat emulsifies.  Does oil emulsify?  I’m guessing no because you can usually see the oil after frying.  Thanks.

Yes, oil also emulsifies. My guess is if you repeated the recipe with 2 tsp oil instead of fat you would end up with a similar result. And I agree, 2 tsp is not so much, I'm not sure if your quantities but of I was cooking something like this for two people I would use 2 tablespoons.
